# How to add custom value in charts for bottom label in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts, swift5.7

I have to show [0, 25, 50, 75, 100] with dollar sign in Charts using swift iOS

[image]

```
 var xValue = [25.0, 50.0]
var dollarValue = ["$25", "$50", "$75", "$100"]
```

Added in view didLoad

```
  rightAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:     dollarValue)
 func updateCharts() {
    var chartDataEntry = [BarChartDataEntry]()
    let spaceForBar =  10.0;
    for i in 0..<xValue.count {
        let value = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i)  * spaceForBar, y: xValue[i])
        chartDataEntry.append(value)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: chartDataEntry, label: "10x In-Store ")
    chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()

    let chartMain = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    chartMain.barWidth = 5.0
    
    horizontalBarChartContainnerView.animate(yAxisDuration: 0.5)
    horizontalBarChartContainnerView.data = chartMain
}
```

I wanted to show 0 $25 $50 $75 $100 instead of 0 10 20 30 40 50

Comment: Add code that you used to draw chart

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom formatter

```
public class CustomAxisValueFormatter: NSObject, AxisValueFormatter {
    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return "$\(Int(value))"
    } }
```

and set the axis value formatter to your custom formatter

```
xAxis.valueFormatter = CustomAxisValueFormatter()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This code is working fine

public class CustomAxisValueFormatter: AxisValueFormatter {
var labels: [String] = []
public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
    let count = self.labels.count
    guard let axis = axis, count > 0 else {
        return ""
    }
    let factor = axis.axisMaximum / Double(count)
    let index = Int((value / factor).rounded())
    if index >= 0 && index < count {
        return self.labels[index]
    }
    return ""
}
 }
```

Add inside of viewDidLoad()

```
 rightAxis.axisMaximum = 4
 let customAxisValueFormatter  = CustomAxisValueFormatter()
 customAxisValueFormatter.labels =  ["$25", "$80", "$75", "$100"]
```